# assertion failed errors when trying to git subtree split

Tags: windows, git, github, subtree

I have a private GitHub repo (which I can't share here) cloned locally. I want to split a subfolder in this repo into a new subtree repo. I'm following these instructions [**Using Git subtrees for repository separation**](http://makingsoftware.wordpress.com/2013/02/16/using-git-subtrees-for-repository-separation/) (under **Splitting code into its own repository**).

My specific command is:

```
> git subtree split -P .\plugins\rg-feed-client -b rg-feed-client
```

however it fails with exactly 24 "assertion failed" error messages that look like this:

```
1/     26 (0)2/     26 (1)assertion failed:  [ plugins/rg-feed-client = .\plugins\rg-fee
3/     26 (2)assertion failed:  [ plugins/rg-feed-client = .\plugins\rg-feed-client ]
...
26/     26 (25)assertion failed:  [ plugins/rg-feed-client = .\plugins\rg-feed-client ]
```

If I try any other subfolder, the exact same happens. I have no idea what may be wrong here... HELP!

My repo has 2 remotes: origin, and a remote for an existing subtree that I added to my repo.

Comment: p.s. the same error happens with or without the branch part, -b rg-feed-client

Comment: you should not have trailing and leading characters on the -P parameter -P plugins/rg-feed-client and as you said below you should not use backslashes but forward slashes

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This was probably due to the backslashes in --prefix (I was running Windows back then.)

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helped me.

Answer (score 8):

`Split -P` can't gracefully handle directory path . Use following command instead -

```
git subtree split --prefix=plugins/rg-feed-client -b rg-feed-client
```

A few points to remember -

1. Avoid prefixing `./` with path i.e instead of `./plugins/rg-feed-client` use `plugins/rg-feed-client`
2. Avoid any trailing `/` after the path , i.e ***NO*** `plugins/rg-feed-client/`

Comment: It seems `git subtree` can handle trailing `/` now, but `./` prefix is still a problem.